# MyXls lib doesn't edit existing file

Tags: c#, xls

Trying to edit my file with MyXls:

```
        XlsDocument doc = new XlsDocument(InputFilePath);

        Worksheet sheet = doc.Workbook.Worksheets[InputSheet.Substring(0, InputSheet.Length - 1)];

        foreach (var row in sheet)
        {
            if (row.CellCount > 1)
            {
                Cell firstCell = row.GetCell(1);
                firstCell.Font.Weight = FontWeight.Bold;
            }
        }
        doc.Save();//Here is a nullreference Exception without any explanations
```

It seems that MyXLs cannot write into my file; example is for creating new file only. If so, what is the best way to copy all the contents of one xls file into another with this lib?

Answer (score 1):

FileStream file = new FileStream(inputFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
doc.Save(file);
file.Close();